# How to explain this trigonometric problem properly?

Tags: undergraduate-education, trigonometry

Trigonometry has some complex stuff, but sometimes students have trouble with the beginning, the basics.

As an example, here's what seems to be a simple question:

> $$2cos(x)=1$$ $$0°≤x≤360°$$
>   *Find the possible values of* $x$

For students, this question may not seem as simple to them. Is there a good way I can explain this question, and these classes of questions in general?

If you can, provide an example question and an example explanation.

Comment: What is the $cos^{-1}\times (\frac{7}{6})$ supposed to be?  Using improper notation certainly would confuse the students.

Comment: There are no solutions to that equation as $\cos x\leq 1$ for $x$ real.

Comment: I suspect many students will be confused when you say "find the value" when there is more than one value satisfying the constraints you gave.

Comment: In case it helps, I found the following on an old trigonometry test of mine just now: Find all values of $\theta$ such that $\theta$ is in the interval $\left[0^{\text{o}},\,360^{\text{o}}\right)$ and $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2}$. If there are no such values of $\theta$, then state this.

Comment: To revisit this question (and since I have a few moments left in my lunch break), the way I used to explain how to see the "big picture" when solving these types of questions is to reduce the equation(s) to SINE = constant(s) and/or COSINE = constant(s), and then draw a unit circle with appropriate vertical and/or horizontal lines, a method that makes use of the fact that SINE corresponds to $y$-coordinates on the unit circle and COSINE corresponds to $x$-coordinates on the unit circle. Thus, for $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{2},$ sketch $x^2+y^2=1$ along with $x=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: The point of the unit circle is to see how many solutions and which quadrants they're in. The exact values come from knowing the values to the reference angles and how to make use of this in other quadrants. This isn't a good week for me --- very busy at work --- so I can't really say much more now, but I might come back to this in a week or two if no one else has posted much.

Comment: @TheBitByte: If you don't use the unit circle, how have you defined cosine? The "x-coordinate on the unit circle" definition seems to be the most natural one for this sort of class (given that they probably haven't seen stuff like power series or differential equations).

Comment: I just remembered that I posted some "tips" about the unit circle in my answer to [Tips for understanding the unit circle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31163/tips-for-understanding-the-unit-circle), and perhaps some of the things I said (or others who posted an answer or a comment said) could be of use to you.

Comment: @TheBitByte: What are those "algebraic methods"? Since you haven't said what definition of cosine they're using (as far as I can see), it's not clear how they would solve this problem at all.

Comment: I believe the reason everyone is mentioning the unit circle @TheBitByte, is because it's impossible to solve this without reference to angles that *don't fit inside a right-angled triangle*. There are two solutions, one is $x=60^\circ$ and the other is $x=120^\circ$. Only one of those makes sense in terms of angles in a right-angled triangle, so you need some method to extend cos beyond 90$^\circ$. That's why everyone is saying to use the unit circle, it's the most natural way to extend the trig ratios into trig functions beyond 90$^\circ$.

Comment: Also, I completely disagree that just because something *can* be done without diagrams, then this implies it *should* be done without diagrams. Personally, I draw a unit circle every single time I solve an equation like this. Every single time. Why would I expect my students not to?

Comment: Then it seems like you need to change your question. We all are responding to you in what we think your question says it's about. We think that using the unit circle *is* a good way to explain it, just like you asked. If you want something else, then please edit your original question make it clearer what you want.

Comment: @TheBitByte: I think you might still be missing the point here: I'm not saying you *should* use the unit circle here because it's more convenient or anything like that. I'm saying you *must* use the unit circle here because the problem literally makes no sense without it. It's kind of worrying that you don't seem to be aware of this. (If you disagree, please explain how to compute $\cos(120^\circ)$ without reference to the unit circle.)

Comment: @TheBitByte: I know. I'm asking whether you, personally, can compute $\cos(120^\circ)$ without the unit circle or methods clearly beyond the scope of your class (like power series or differential equations). Your question asks to "find the possible values of x" for a range of values that extends beyond where cosine is defined via right triangles; your responses seem to suggest you can somehow compute it outside that range anyway without using the unit circle definition.

Comment: @TheBitByte IMO, you are making it harder on the students than it should be.  At this point, I feel as though you are confusing the students more than helping them.  To comment on the unit circle, I agree it is rather tedious referring to a unit circle for every problem, but referring to the unit circle to see that $\sin(x)=\sin(180-x)$ is not at all a bad idea.  You have to think about this from the students' perspective too.

Comment: @TheBitByte Some of the best proofs are [Proofs without words](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/)

Comment: Often times the unit circle, is the **easiest and least convoluted** way to explain trigonometry for $\theta>90^\circ$.  The greatest you could do, algebraically, is to derive the sum of angles formula $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$, but only when $a+b<90^\circ$, show the function is analytic, and use the above in combination with analytic continuation, to define it for $a+b>90^\circ$.  Now, would you call that "teaching students trigonometry", or real analysis?

Comment: @TheBitByte Neither (I honestly don't remember either).  Instead, remember what the unit circle ***is***, $\cos$ in the $x$, $\sin$ in the $y$, and from there, show that $\sin(x)=\sin(180-x)$.  Believe me (and it appears your students are evidence of this) when I tell you brute memorizing those identities are not going to happen.  But memorizing a few properties of the unit circle?  That, that is doable.

Comment: The ***only*** formula I have **ever** memorized without understanding why it is, was the quadratic formula.  But, by letting students understand why such a seemingly simple identity holds true (especially with pictures, those work well for students), it will be better experience than an hour of "So $\sin(x)=\sin(180-x)$.

Comment: @TheBitByte The graph of $\sin$ has no simple algebraic explanation using $\sin(x)=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$.  And the problem with your "simple rules" is that students will easily confuse them.  On the other hand, I find the unit circle less confusing, and I don't even need to know much about the unit circle.

Comment: @TheBitByte [Yes actually, I do](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/734790/272831)  Furthermore, the visual provides more information than first sight would probably show.

Comment: @TheBitByte It is the ***most*** basic parametric equation: $y=\sin(t)$ and $t=x$, where $t$ represents how long the animation has been running.  On the other hand, how would **define** the graph first?  You are only digging yourself into an increasingly confusing hole, so why not just choose the easier and widely accepted answer?

Comment: Another more analytical perspective: [Intuitive understanding of sine and cosine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392/intuitive-understanding-of-the-derivatives-of-sin-x-and-cos-x/1093#1093)

Comment: Anyways, even if you don't prefer this personally, your students will probably like this explanation much more.  Its not always about how you like to teach.  You come to this site to learn how to teach your students more intuitively, more ingeniously, but most importantly, to teach your students successfully.

Comment: Deriving a graph **period** of the trigonometric functions without the unit circle is difficult.  And I was not the one to say we should graph the sine function, as that was your idea.  My point was on the symmetry of the trig functions and how they are easily visualized with the unit circle over unintuitive identities that make no sense with your given definition of the trig functions.

Comment: @TheBitByte Yes.  Set $y=\sin(t)$ and $t=3x$, where $t$ is time.

Comment: Why not try graphing $y=a\sin(bx+c)?\qquad\frac ya=\sin(t)$ and $t=bx+c$, so we have the $y$ axis with units $\frac ya$.

Comment: Indeed, it isn't a magical solution for everything.  But why not use the magic where it works?

Comment: @TheBitByte: You still haven't explained how to get values of cosine or sine outside the range $(0, \pi/2)$ without using the unit circle (unsurprisingly, because it's impossible). How do you know $\sin(x) = \sin(\pi - x)$? Without using the unit circle, you don't. You can say something vague about "just look at the graph", but without using the unit circle, you don't know what the graph looks like, either — because you literally haven't defined it. No wonder your students are confused.

Comment: @DanielHast And I think it is safe to assume analytic stuff is out of the ballpark big time as well.

Comment: @TheBitByte: Sorry, but you're still not getting it. It's not a matter of efficiency — I'm saying what you're asking is *logically impossible*. You *cannot* graph something that hasn't been defined, and your stated definition of cosine and sine only makes sense for acute angles, not arbitrary angles.

Comment: @TheBitByte: Okay, if you're not expecting your students to use that definition in this context, what definition do you expect them to use? You seem to believe that cosine and sine can be defined for all real numbers without reference to the unit circle (and in a manner appropriate for the level of your class); in that case, what definition are you using?

Comment: @TheBitByte: You don't have to repeat the definitions every time, but you do have to have definitions in the first place. You said you want to avoid using the unit circle in this problem, so that means you must be relying on some other definition. But the only other definition you gave is the right triangle definition, which *only* makes sense for acute angles, so it clearly can't be the definition you're using for this question, either. (Making sure all the different definitions of one notion are equivalent is a separate matter, and not at issue here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a problem of unclear or inapplicable definitions. As stated in the comments, it sounds like you've given the students the following definition: Given an angle $t$, we consider a right triangle with an angle of measure $t$, and define $\cos(t)$ to be the ratio of the side length of this triangle adjacent to the given angle to the length of the hypotenuse.

The problem is, this definition only makes sense when $0 < t < \pi/2$ (or, if you prefer degrees, $0^\circ < t < 90^\circ$. Indeed, a right triangle's other two angles have measure strictly between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$. But you've given the students a problem that assumes cosine has been defined for any $t$ between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$, which makes no sense with the definition they've been given!

I would recommend instead defining cosine as the $x$-coordinate on the unit circle. A simple diagram (drawing an appropriate right triangle inside the unit circle) shows this agrees with the other definition for angles in the first quadrant, but the unit circle definition also clearly makes sense for any angle. Plus, it makes it much easier to reason about this kind of question — just draw the line $x = 1/2$ and see where it intersects the unit circle, then use geometric reasoning to find the angles.

I'm still a bit confused about what you mean by "algebraic methods", by the way. Both the triangle definition and the unit circle definition are geometric, so you really can't compute values of cosine using these definitions without appealing to geometry.

Comment: @TheBitByte: I still don't understand how you expect your students to solve the problem (or even make sense of the problem statement) *without* appealing to the unit circle definition. Could you post a solution along the lines of what you'd want your students to give?

Comment: @TheBitByte Yeah... no.  And not to mention radians to degrees will only confuse them more.

Answer (score 1):

For the easy memorizing of special points:

$$\cos(0^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt4}2\\\cos(30^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt3}2\\\cos(45^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt2}2\\\cos(60^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt1}2\\\cos(90^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt0}2$$

Same thing for $\sin(\theta)$ but going backwards.  Then it should be easy to see that $x=60^\circ$ is one answer.  From there, I would try to show them the unit circle and how it is symmetric.  Using that, it should become obvious that $300^\circ$ is the only other answer.

Beyond that, either you are teaching some pretty advanced trigonometry, it happens to be a special special point, like $\cos(15^\circ)$ using the half-angle theorem, or you give them calculators.  I can't imagine it being any other way, unless you were teaching a numerical analysis type of class.

Comment: Why would you ask students to *memorize* values of cosine or sine? It seems like a pointless exercise that short-circuits the actual (and actually interesting) geometric reasoning that goes into finding those values.

Comment: @DanielHast Well, after learning what sine and cosine mean, it helps to memorize these values since they appear more than other values.  And as to how much of an exercise this is, I think it's really easy.  If you take a look, there is a pretty simple pattern, one that takes only moments to memorize.

Comment: Why it does help to memorize those values? What's the point if you don't understand *why* cosine and sine have those special values?

Comment: @DanielHast Well, clearly by the time one gets to this, they should have a basic understanding of *why* cosine and sine have those special values.  This answer doesn't serve to teach trigonometry, just to help others recall certain values more easily.  Your answer does a wonderful job of that, and I applaud, but the OP still isn't satisfied.

Comment: If you understand the reasoning behind those special values, tricks to memorize them shouldn't be necessary. Sine and cosine of $\pi/4$ come from an isosceles right triangle; sine and cosine of $\pi/3$ and $\pi/6$ come from half an equilateral triangle. The Pythagorean theorem gives the side lengths in both cases, no tricks required.

Comment: @danielhast for the same reason the OP avoids the unit circle, you'd end up having to remember how to construct those triangles, and as far as remembering goes, my answer is arguably simplest.

Answer (score 1):

If students are struggling to understand a relatively simple trig equation like the one given, I find that graphs often help. We can sketch y=2cos(x) and y=1, and get a feeling for how many solutions to expect in the given interval. Moreover symmetries of the graphs can help determine the full set of solutions, much as the unit circle approach does. Interestingly, I believe in the UK the unit circle development of trig functions isn't such a common approach but many teachers use the (IMO awful) 'CAST' diagram for solving trig equations, devoid of deeper understanding.

Comment: I feel like there's a logical gap there, similar to in the OP's attempt at explaining the problem: Your post makes it sound like the unit circle definition is optional, but how is cosine even defined for arbitrary angles if not by the unit circle? For the graph of cosine to have any symmetries in the first place, it has to be defined for angles outside the first quadrant.

Comment: I didn't intend for it to sound optional - I completely agree with you in terms of extending the meaning of cosine beyond acute angles. However, when it comes to the specific skill of finding multiple solutions from an equation, I've found that my students have typically preferred the graphical point of view over the unit circle representation.